# How to escape backspace in XML with Java?

Tags: java, xml

How to escape backspace ('\b') in XML with Java? StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: escapeXml is deprecated, do you still get a problem with escapeXml10 or escapeXml11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backspace (0x08) is not a legal character in XML 1.0; no amount of escaping will change this. It is a legal character in XML 1.1, provided that it is written in escaped form as `&#x8;` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use it unicode value `String backspace = "\u0008";`

Comment: Yep. Before Maven repo for Aapche commons-lang3, 3.4.0 is available, this works. But the code actually is,  `CharSequence scTarget = String.valueOf('\b');
    CharSequence scReplacement = "\\u0008";
    s = s.replace(scTarget, scReplacement);`